# Pandas corrwith with method = "spearman" doesn't work

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, methods, correlation

I'm trying to use corrwith with `method='spearman'`.
From the [documentation of corrwith](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.corrwith.html), there is such a method but when I try to use it I get this error:

> `TypeError: corrwith() got an unexpected keyword argument 'method'`.

Could you please help?

Comment: provide your code and full error trace and which version of pandas do you use?

Comment: what is your pandas version?

Comment: It's 0.22.0 version. This is the traceback:
`TypeError: corrwith() got an unexpected keyword argument 'method'`